# Convert to image in c#

Tags: c#, image

It is not just capture the form to image

Example, I have a GridView which is bigger then Main Form.
If there was a many data in GridView, It has a Scroll Bar.
But I have to Convert to Image all Data in Grid
So how can I do??

Comment: You could [undock then use DrawToImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852666/c-sharp-winform-drawtobitmap-offscreen)

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918450/winforms-how-to-print-the-whole-of-a-form-including-unseen-parts/30924473#30924473) and for huge sizes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360110/how-to-overcome-the-winforms-control-drawtobitmap-method-large-size-limitatio/27406432#27406432)