# Bitmap from a whole Windows Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, drawing

In my Visual Studio 2015 Project I have a Form (tabPage) that is bigger as the screen, so one have to scroll. How can I draw the whole Form (not only visible area) into a bitmap?

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(tabPage1.Width, tabPage1.Height);
tabPage1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
```

The code above draws only the visible part of the Form.

Answer (score 1):

Looks very similar to the question asked here:

[Saving Panel as JPEG, only saving visible areas c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001576/saving-panel-as-jpeg-only-saving-visible-areas-c-sharp)

Here is the accepted answer from this post:

> Try following
>
> ```
>    public void DrawControl(Control control,Bitmap bitmap)
>     {
>         control.DrawToBitmap(bitmap,control.Bounds);
>         foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
>         {
>             DrawControl(childControl,bitmap);
>         }
>     }
>
>    public void SaveBitmap()
>     {
>         Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.panel1.Width, this.panel.Height);
>
>        this.panel.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.panel.Width, this.panel.Height));
>         foreach (Control control in panel1.Controls)
>         {
>             DrawControl(control, bmp);
>         }
>
>        bmp.Save("d:\\panel.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
>     }
> ```
>
> Here is my result:
>
> **Form ScreenShot** :
>
> [image]
>
> **Saved bitmap** :
>
> [image]
>
> As you can see there is TextBox wich is not visible on form but is present in saved bitmap